# twitter boostrap modal trigger when clicks on outside the dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is there an option in the bootstrap modal to trigger the event if the user clicks outside the dialog?

For example: I would like to add **animated shake** css when user click away from modal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the event **shown** you can fire a new function that when someone click on the body (so outside the modal) you do something.

Remember to add also `event.stopPropagation()` to don't close the modal when you click outside.

Here an example:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    // your function...
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
})
```

---

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  $('body').off('click');
});
```

Comment: after closing the modal, event is triggering whenever I click the body. I tried

 `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#ajax_loader").modal('show')
  .on('shown', function () {
      $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    
   $("#ajax_loader").addClass("animated shake");
   e.stopPropagation();
  });
  });
 })`

Comment: Sure, then on modal **hidden** event you should `.off()` the click on the body as well. Do you need example for that as well?

Comment: added the off event as well.

Comment: thanks for reply. Its working as expected
but increase of event trigger for every click function.
for example, I inspect with alert inside the body click function, I have two alerts if I click the modal second time and three alerts on third time....

Comment: try to increase z-index of the modal and set body to 0, it may help... not sure about that, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something...
})
```

(Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Comment: Adding discription to your answer would add more value to it, rather than only adding link.

Comment: This will fire when the modal is closed, not necessarily when clicked outside it (i.e. if the modal can be closed by other means).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specifically for Bootstrap, but it should be possible to do what you asked about.

The following Code snippet detects a click anywhere on the page. It then examines what was clicked on and decides what to do based on that.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

        //Dont hide the button if it's a link or input that was clicked
        if ((e.target.nodeName == 'A') || (e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT')) return;

        HideSubmenus();
    });
```

In your case, you could probably check if it's not a Div (and thereby not the Modal).

Comment: <div
            className={ "modal modal-fade d-block show"}
            role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
            aria-hidden="true"
            onClick={(e) => {
                alert(e.currentTarget.nodeName)
                
            }}
        >

Comment: it does print div all the time

Answer (score 0):

Animated Shakes is the default feature of Modal popover. You just need to set **backdrop:'static'** to do this. This will prevent the popover to close and enable shaking animation when someone will click outside of modal.

```
$('#myModal').modal({
     backdrop:'static', show: true
})
```

For more information please have a look at [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html)